# Facebook search: find dead people

Tags: facebook

Is it somehow possible to search Facebook and in return get dead people? In [Facebook's help search description](https://www.facebook.com/help/103764609715185) it is mentioned that there's possibility to find people by key words - is there any for this type of search?

As my intentions might seem controversial to some, there is a reason for this kind of search: I am interested in how articles like [this one](http://www.theloop.ca/dead-facebook-users-will-soon-outnumber-the-living/) gather information for statistics.

Comment: Isn't it reasonable that the authors of that article contacted Facebook to get the numbers? I don't know if this helps, but a memorialized account will put "Remembering" in front of the person's name.

Comment: It helps a lot actually, to the point where I can accept is as an answer if you provide one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to natively search Facebook for memorialized accounts.

There are ways to programmatically search Facebook users in general as well as see for specific accounts whether memorialization occurred.

However, that's not in the scope of this site.